# Bootstrap modal is not working with carousel slide

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to show a bootstrap modal above a carousel slide.  but nothing is showing up.  when I manually trigger it from the chrome browser console, I can see from the logs that the modal is getting triggered. but it is not getting showed to the user.  is there anything I can do?

Comment: Please post some relevant code that recreates the problem. It's possible that you just need a larger `z-index` for the modal so that it overlaps the slideshow, but it's impossible to know without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding a larger z-index for the modal fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

download bootstrap-modal-carousel.css and bootstrap-modal-carousel.js (you can find them searching on google) and then try this example:

```
<link href="bootstrap-modal-carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="bootstrap-modal-carousel.js"/></script/>

<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-local="#myCarousel">Demo</button>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fit" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#777:#555/text:First slide" alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>First slide label</h3>
        <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img data-src="holder.js/750x400/auto/#666:#444/text:Second slide" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Second slide label</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img data-src="holder.js/600x300/auto/#555:#333/text:Third slide" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Third slide label</h3>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="modal fade modal-fullscreen force-fullscreen" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Provide some relevant code, or at least a description of the solution, in case the linked content disappears at some point in the future.